# How to call mysql stored procedure in kitura application

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, kitura, server-side-swift

I need to call MySQL stored procedures in kitura application and use it for the query result. how can I do that

Answer (score 1):

The use of Stored Procedures is not something that the current release of the SwiftKuery framework has support for.

If you feel that Stored Procedure support would be of benefit to the community then please feel free to raise an issue on [SwiftKueryMySQL](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/SwiftKueryMySQL).